# How do I expose my REST API?

Tags: rest, networking

I'm creating an app for iOS that will use CocoaHTTPServer to provide some RESTful web services. Is there a normal convention for publishing the api so that the available calls can be discovered by another device?

Comment: You'd broadcast its existence with Bonjour. For docs, I'd look at places like Github's docs and see if there's anything you like. I have no idea how you advertise the service details in a way that can be parsed, though. Looking forward to seeing answers. :)

Comment: That would be to expose the web server itself, but for the APIs available for restful calls. Is there a normal convention for publishing those? Like /restapi would return JSON of restful methods?